# Remote Proc fails to load FreeRTOS Elf

Tags: elf, cortex-m, omap, remote-process

I am using [this port of FreeRTOS](https://github.com/n-aizu/freertos-multicore) and I am loading it onto the Cortex-M3 within an OMAP4430. This works fine using the remote proc framework and I am able to use RPMsg to communicate with it.

Sometimes, however, rproc fails to load the elf and gives the following error:

```
rproc remoteproc1: bad phdr da 0x0 mem 0x10310
rproc remoteproc1: Failed to load program segments: -22
rproc remoteproc1: rproc_boot() failed -22
```

This seems to happen when the size of the elf file gets too large: this happens when the size is 377331 bytes but does not happen when I simply remove a bunch of print statements and bring the size down to 342563 bytes.

I have tracked the error message down to this piece of code: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/remoteproc/remoteproc_elf_loader.c?v=3.9#L188. It seems that rproc_da_to_va is unable to find a segment in memory large enough to fit the ELF.

How can I make sure that there is enough memory for the size of my ELF? Can I tell the kernel that I specifically want a certain region preallocated for this kind of thing? Is there some way to ensure that this part of my ELF remains small?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the FreeRTOS configuration constants `configTEXT_SIZE` and `configDATA_SIZE` agree with the amounts demanded by your linker script. For example, if your linker script contains

```
MEMORY
{
  TEXT (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 1M
  DATA (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x80000000, LENGTH = 1M
}
```

then you should set `configTEXT_SIZE` and `configDATA_SIZE` to `0x100000`.